# Jndi, hibernate and entitymanager persist and flush method no record in database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, transactions

I have problem with flush data to PostgreSQL database in SpringMVC.
When i use entityManager.flush().

The Table is created in PosgreSQL, I can use pgadmin3 and it exists but the problem was that after i passed element from controller to the ImageDaoImpl it didn't push record to the database;/

```
@Repository

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ImageDaoImpl implements ImageDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void register(Image image) { 
        em.persist(image);
        em.flush(); 
        return;
    }

}
```

It threw me an error while i wanted to do register method.
`javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`

I tried to do:

```
    @Transactional
public void register(Image image) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(image);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return;
}
```

but it threw me:

```
threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
```

Firstly I thought that something is wrong and add fristly `@PersistenceContext`.

I found [EntityManager cannot use persist to save element to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937394/entitymanager-cannot-use-persist-to-save-element-to-databasesolved)

and tried to add

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

and

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
         class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

But I then i thought how it isn't possible to attach manager:
Then i got error like this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.JdbcTransactionObjectSupport
```

What to do next? How i can integrate the `<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/spring-quickstart/persistence" id="entityManagerFactory" ...` with the transactionManager?
What is the difference between them? Which one i should use to connect with database?

Maybe there is another problem which i couldn't see.

I have set all database connection but problem with flush made me crazy. I didn't try to read information from Entity in browser, before that i want to push information to database.

I read 
[Spring jta-transaction-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963612/spring-jta-transaction-manager?rq=1)

and tried to comment that line

but it threw me:
   (MSC service thread 1-2) Context initialization failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject

Why it couldn't find the proper solution:
[EntityManager persist() method does not insert record to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759894/entitymanager-persist-method-does-not-insert-record-to-database)
Where should I register class Image to make the transaction?

Here is the fragment of the Controller.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String save(
                @ModelAttribute("uploadForm") ImageDaoImpl uploadForm,
                        Model map, BindingResult result) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
                           ...
                           String filePath = fileCatalog + orgName;                                        
                        Image memberImage = new Image();
                        memberImage.setFilePath(filePath);             
                        imageDao.register(memberImage);

                                 ...
                }
            }
```

I create the object and set one value which i need in database. The file i get is save in the hard-drive. I need it later for my another program.
It is good way to register object in the application. Maybe it is a reason that it isn't flush to the database?

At the end I am attaching my configurations files:

ImageDomain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="IMAGES")
public class Image {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="CONTENTTYPE")
    private String contentType;

    @Column(name="LENGTH")
    private Integer length;

    @Column(name="ISPOCESSED")
    private boolean isprocessed;

    @Column(name="CONTENT")
    @Lob
    private Blob content;

    @Column(name="FILEPATH")
    private String filepath;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    public String getFilePath(){
        return filepath;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }
    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }
    public Blob getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(Blob content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public Integer getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public void setLength(Integer length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

}
```

META-INF/spring/ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springmvc.trophy.domain"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springmvc.trophy.repo"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

META-INF/spring/infrastructure.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!-- JDNI name for EntityManagerFactory is defined in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml -->


    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/spring-quickstart/persistence" id="entityManagerFactory"
                     expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:jta-transaction-manager /> 

</beans>
```

META-INF/Persistance.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed data 
            source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
        <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/spring-quickstart-ds.xml, you 
            can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-quickstart-ds.xml -->
         <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ImagesDS</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
           <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
                value="java:jboss/spring-quickstart/persistence" />             
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />


        </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

webapp/WEB-INF/images-ds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference this 
        in META-INF/persistence.xml -->
     <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ImagesDS"
        pool-name="kitchensink-quickstart" enabled="true" jta="false" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dermadb</connection-url>
        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
        <driver>postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>username</user-name>
            <password>dbpassword</password>
        </security>
    </datasource> 
</datasources>
```

I deployed module for PostgreSQL: in webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
            <module name="org.postgresql"/>
            <!-- <module name="com.h2database.h2"/> -->
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue.

Firstly i thought there is something wrong with transaction manager and I add aspectj to the project.

META-INF/spring/infrastructure.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I add also library to Maven - file: POM.XML

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

At the end I realized that I don't need to use commit and close transaction etc. As you can see in my first post. The Entity Factory and Manager are passed thought the `@PersistenceContext` and I can use `entityManager.persist(object)` to pass the object into database and transaction will end.

My mistake was during the setting the connection to database in persistence.xml
I used resource local in this line:

```
<persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

and the in the next step i used JTA to connect with database. Here was the whole problem.

I change that line to

```
<persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
```

and it occurred that everything is fine and object is flushed to the database.

Thanks Pavel Horal for your help and I hope that this answer will help anyone else. You need always look out on details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like class-path problem. Are you trying to share Spring libraries? If not, verify, that you have `spring-orm` in your dependencies.

Comment: I checked class-paths. I have spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE in my maven dependencies. What do you mean by share spring libraries? It isn't enough to include it in maven?

Comment: "Share spring libraries" - if you are trying to put them on shared class loader... but you are probably not doing this. If you are using Maven, check your dependency list to check for JAR version conflicts.

Comment: Hi.I am sorry I'm late write off the answer. If i have conflicts in Maven the server wouldn't start. Eclipse is checking the JARs in Maven. I checked [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155991/spring-annotation-driven-transaction-manager) They write something about aspectj and i think there can be problem that i don't implement something.

Comment: I added <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> and libraries aspecj to maven but the commit or flush in DAO still don't work :/ Does anyone have idea how to solve that problem?